# PHP array element '%count%' (pecentage 'count' percentage)

Tags: php

I'm fairly convinced this is placeholder code left in an old project. I've never seen it before, can find anything about this on Google and [the project it comes from is long since dead](https://github.com/SilexAndFriends/Silex/blob/3.1.x/src/Silex/Application/TranslationTrait.php#L49).

```
public function transChoice($id, $number, array $parameters = [], $domain = 'messages', $locale = null)
    {
        $parameters['%count%'] ??= $number;
        return $this->trans($id, $parameters, $domain, $locale);
    }
```

What exactly is `$parameters['%count%']` doing here? The '%count%' array element reference specifically.

Comment: This same pattern is found in the Symfony Translation component: https://github.com/symfony/translation/search?q=%25count%25 That being said I have no idea what it does.

Comment: Lovely. Thank you for that lead. I'll try to make sense of it.